# Partial time-based trade exit in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

After certain number of bars - say 100 bars, if my trade hasn't exited with the original stop or take profit, I would like to exit out 50% of the trade at market value and modify the original exit order with new profit and stop loss values. Is that possible? How could I do it in Pinescript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `barssince` function to count the bars, `strategy.position_size` to detect the long entry and `qty_percent` argument of the `strategy.exit` function:

```
wasLongEntry = strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size != strategy.position_size[1]
barsFromLong = barssince(wasLongEntry)

if barsFromLong >= 100
    *check for stop and take profit*
    ...
    strategy.exit( ..., qty_percent = 50, ... ) 
    //then overwrite SL/TP
    sl := ...
    tp := ...
```